# Raid 1 from already initialized disk

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, raid1

I have 4TB disk (A) with data in it. Now I've bought a new 4TB disk (B), and I want to start a RAID1 so that B becomes the mirror of A, without loosing data on A. I'm under linux with mdadm tool.

The only guides I've found by googling are referring to a typical situation where both A and B must be initialized and formatted.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy.

- Make a degraded RAID 1 array with the new/empty drive (Drive B).  Set devices to 2.
- Format new MD array and copy files from Drive A to new MD array.
- Verify data then delete/empty/format Drive A.
- Add the now empty Drive A to the MD array and let it sync.
- Done.

Comment: Correct. I found this complete guide, thanks: https://debian-administration.org/article/238/Migrating_To_RAID1_Mirror_on_Sarge

Answer (score 1):

If you still have 50% free space on your old disk then you can:

- create two partitions on your new disk
- copy the data from your old disk to the *second* partition on your new disk
- make the new disk bootable
- verify that the data that you copied over is OK on the new disk
- repartion the old disk like the new one
- make a md1 raid over the *first* partions on both disk
- copy the data to the md1 raid
- make the md1 partition bootable
- recheck that the data on the md1 raid is OK

**BE WARE: you make one mistake and you loose *ALL* your data**

- possibly - *I have not checked* - you can then delete the second partition afterwards
- and grow the md1/first partition to fill up all the space
- extend the filesystem on it

AGAIN: you do one misstep and your data are dead

Comment: This is a nice suggestion. One can also take into account compressing data if less than 50% is free.